# How can I turn my CRUD database application into a REST application?

Tags: php, rest, html, relational-database, crud

I may have gotten myself confused, when reading CRUD vs REST and how they are similar, so I wanted to explicitly ask:  can I turn my CRUD application into a REST application, when I have a specific scenario, and will doing so be of any benefit?

My existing CRUD application uses data in a MySQL table that is mostly passive, but from time to time it needs to be updated.  In my case the data represents various dimensions and specs of a motor that are changed or corrected from time to time.  There is also a similar but "higher in concept" use case where instead of modifying the data in-place, it is versioned and historical records are kept.  That is, say the current "row" of data is first inactivated, but is otherwise left in the database, and a new row of data is added with a new version number, which is then made active.  That new data is then read for any future motor computations.

The CRUD has the following parts:
* HTML form, submitting which transfers data to an "add/edit" script, which redirects to "view" script that shows the added/updated data.

I don't have a clue of how to convert this into a REST application or if I need to, or of doing so will make my life or someone's life better.

Can I have a more concrete example of what it will mean to convert my particular use case from CRUD, to REST?  Will I need to change any URLs, interfaces, event handling, etc?

Comment: I think you're confusing things. CRUD vs REST are nearly orthogonal concepts. REST is a data interface. Use REST if you are going to have web-based clients talking to it, but your application at heart will still be a CRUD app.

Comment: by web based clients do you mean automated clients or can it be clients driven by humans?  In my case I have users of the app who use web clients (browsers) to access the app via HTML interfaces over HTTP...

Comment: @whatsisname: Actually, REST is an architectural style, not a data interface.  If you want a data interface, try HTTP.  If you want a data protocol, try JSON.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: a style for an interface, not an application architecture. You can bolt a REST interface onto just about anything, it imposes few to no requirements on how the underlying system works.

Answer (score 5):

**CRUD** is a term that refers to the four most used activities in Data Oriented Applications: **Create** (Add, New), **Read** (Get, GetList), **Update** (Modify), **Delete** (Remove). In terms of Database the CRUD maps the **Insert**, **Select**, **Update** & **Delete** SQL-DML (Data Manipulation Language) commands.

**REST** (Representational State Transfer) is a term used in Web Application Development that specify the features or restrictions that **HTTP RESTFul Services**  should have into account: (1) **Client-Server**, (2) **Stateless**, (3) **Cacheable**, (4) **Uniform Interface** (5), **Layered System** & (6) **Code On Demand**.

A well-formed **Layered Architecture for Web Apps** most times includes three layers, **Fronted**, **Middleware** & **Backend**. **REST services** can be built on the Middleware or directly in Backend. Suppose for example you're thinking on build your App over **Strong Standardized Frameworks**, let’s suppose that the *Frontend* will be build using **Googles Angular JS**, *Middleware services* will be build using **Node JS & Express JS** and *Backend* will rely on **.NET Web API**.

*REST uses HTTP verbs to map CRUD operations*: GET (Read), POST (Create), Put (Update) & Delete (Delete). **The key here is that RESTful compliant services uses HTTP Verbs to perform CRUD operation**. In the Frontend side, the JavaScript code for consuming the REST service migth be similar to:

```
angular.module('RESTApp', [])
.controller('CtrlUsers', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://appdomain.restAPI/users', {id: 1}).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        });
});
```

Finally most recent structural patterns for define Layered Applications uses **Model View Controller** (*ASP.Net MVC, Spring MVC, PHP Laravel*,...) Design Pattern. In the data access case well know **ORMs Frameworks** such as **.Net Entity Framework** or **Hibernate** are used to access relational databases. All this stuff must be understand in order to **design & construct well-formed RESTful Applications**.